# having using default action of the kernel to handle the singal SIGABRT sometimes does not terminate process

Tags: linux, signals, sigabrt, systemctl

In the Application with multiple threads spawning across , raise the SIGABRT ( using raise(SIGABRT) ) in case of failure , have designed the signal handler such that it should execute the default action for the signal. however sometimes when the signal SIGBRT raised, the process does not terminate hence no core file generated.

```
This is the part of the section of handling SIGABRT 
syslog(LOG_ALERT, "Daemon exiting");
signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
kill(getpid(), sig);
```

in the log file, I get the traces as Daemon exiting however I dont see the core file generated  and I am starting this application through systemctl where I have the  Restart on failure, I do  not see the application restarting and I notice the traces being logged from the threads of this process.

```
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
ExecStart=applcaition name
ExecStop=application name
Restart=on-failure
```

From What I understood , process is not getting terminated by the kernel sometimes, how to debug this and when does the kernel do this crazy things?

Thanks

Comment: The process might not have permission to write the core dump file in its current working directory, or its `RLIMIT_CORE` resource limit might be 0.

Comment: @Ian Abbott , its an intermittent issue. Mark Plotnick suggested sigaction over signal , I read about this, its interesting that its safe to sigaction over signal in multhreads/process application.have replaced and will monitor. Thanks.